# How to check if currentDocument is available

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to put some SSJS code together in which I'd like to check, if currentDocument is available.

I've tried something like:

```
if(currentDocument != undefined)
```

But it just throws a runtime error.

Is it even possible to check if currentDocument is available?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your code prior to this line that sets the currentDocument?

Comment: Hello Dwain, thank you very much for your response. currentDocument is a reserved variable name, that returns the underlying NotesXspDocument and you can use it, if you don't know the name of the form datasource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

if( typeof currentDocument != 'undefined' )

Comment: Hello Tommy, thank you very much for the response. That did the trick! I was close but yet so far away.

Answer (score 3):

If also a null check will throw an exception I'd put this in a try-catch block and the catch block to exit with doing nothing (or maybe just logging some information, setting some scope variables to present the user a message etc.)

Comment: Hello Oliver, thank you very much for your response. That what I was contemplating but I wanted to confirm first, that there is not other way. And yes, checking for null is also throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
if ( requestScope.get('currentDocument') != null )
```